# How do I make an Int in C++ have a limit?

Tags: c++, integer

Is there any way I could ensure an `int` doesn't cross a certain limit? and if it needs to (if the program is adding numbers to the `int` and it crosses the limit) it goes back to 0 and does the job from there?

Comment: Do you want an arbitrary limit or is it a power of 2 kind of limit?

Comment: You could wrap your limited int in a class, such that manipulating the int has to go through accessors (getters) and mutators (setters).  The mutators can guarantee the int has the desired handling for crossing-the-limit behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want the modulo operator `%`.

If the upper limit is `limit` then

```
value = value % limit;  // Or value %= limit
```

will "reset" the `value` back to zero if it's about to pass the limit.

Comment: Upvoted, but OP’s question is not sufficiently clear to make this necessarily correct.

Comment: @Dúthomhas Educated guess... ;)

Comment: And I think you are correct :O)